# I get the error "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars" when trying to calculate the last digit of a Fibonacci number using python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am using Python to find the last digit of a Fibonacci number. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def calc_fib(n):
   if n <= 1:
      return n
   else:
      a=np.arange(n+1,dtype='int64')
      for i in range(2,n+1):
        a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2]
   return a[n]%10

n = int(input())
print(calc_fib(n))
```

The code is working fine for small values of n like when n = 10, it yields output of 5, but when using bigger values of n, it yields the output:

```
/Users/amrsulaiman/Desktop/Algorithms_Coursera/W2_2.py:10: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2]
5
```

The value 5 is wrong. It is supposed to be 9. How to solve this overflow issue and fix my code.

Comment: for what `n` are you getting an overflow, if the number is more than a signed 64bit number you won't be able to store it in an array of `dtype='int64'`.

Comment: for n = 331, the last digit of the output is supposed to be 9, the output given is 5.  The number is big, so is there any way to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the properties of decimal addition is that the least-significant digit of the sum only depends on the least-significant digit of the two numbers being added. So you can do all the calculations with only one digit:

```
def calcFibonacciLastDigit(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    a=0
    b=1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        c = a+b
        if c >= 10:     #max value for c is 18
            c -= 10     #so subtracting 10 will keep c as one digit
        a = b
        b = c
    return c

print(calcFibonacciLastDigit(331))  #prints 9
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting 5 instead of 9 for a `n=331` is that you get an overflow as the 93rd fib number as it is bigger than 2^64. So it gets stored as a negative number. The 94th number will also be incorrect as it uses the 93rd which is incorrect, this continues for all number >92.

This can be avoided by using a normal python array, as ints are not bound in python. Give this a try:

```
def calc_fib(n):
   if n <= 1:
      return n
   else:
      a=[0,1]
      for i in range(2,n+1):
        a.append(a[i-1]+a[i-2])
   return a[n]%10

n = int(input())
print(calc_fib(n))
```